# Active record where record is less than 15 minutes old

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, codeigniter-2

I am using Codeingiter's active record and need to check for entries that are less than 15 minutes old.

I have tried the following, which I thought would work.

```
$this->EE->db->select('entry_id')
             ->from('exp_channel_titles')
             ->where('status', $status)
             ->where('channel_id', $channel)
             ->where(FROM_UNIXTIME('entry_date') >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE))
             ->order_by('entry_date', 'desc');
```

Does anyone know if its possible to do this?

I had hoped this would do work in a where clause"

```
FROM_UNIXTIME('entry_date') >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Comment: That function is going to be evaluated in PHP, not MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html:

> $this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it
>   to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names with backticks.
>
> $this->db->where('MATCH (field) AGAINST ("value")', NULL, FALSE);

So you should be able to pass a string like:

```
 ->where('FROM_UNIXTIME(`entry_date`) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)', NULL, FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is running the code. If my 'entry_date' is in UNIX like so: '1436441790', is there any reason why this shouldn't be working?

Comment: Looking at this, it should actually be \`entry_date\` since a column shouldn't be in quotes, it should be in backticks.