# Query for rows added within 15 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, codeigniter-2

I have a date/time saved in the `entry_date` column of my database - Example: `1436459520`

I am trying to grab only the entries that where added in the last 15 minutes.

I thought the following would work, but nothing is returned.

```
$this->EE->db->select('entry_id, entry_date')
                     ->from('exp_channel_titles')
                     ->where('FROM_UNIXTIME("entry_date") >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)', NULL, FALSE);
```

Firstly, I notice that my dates are being saved as GMT, how can I ensure the current date is GMT to?

Can anyone please tell me if there is anything particularly else wrong here?

**Update**

I have tried:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME("entry_date") >= (now() - interval 15 minute)
```

Which also doesn't work.

Comment: you're subtracting time from a date. e.g. literally doing `2015-07-09 minus 15 minutes`, which gives you `2015-07-09 23:45:00`. e.g. 15 minutes before midnight the day before.

Comment: Maybe try using now() instead of curdate().

Comment: possible duplicate of [Active record where record is less than 15 minutes old](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322314/active-record-where-record-is-less-than-15-minutes-old)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
->where('`entry_date` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())')
```

The unix timestamps are offset from `'1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC` so the timezones will be not be an issue in that format.